# Why does John Reese mostly wear a suit

Tags: character, person-of-interest

I understand that John Reese from *Person of Interest* was a CIA operative and FBI and CIA operatives wear suits. And CIA operatives are mostly shown wearing the same kind of suit.

Still, he got famous with the name of "Man in the Suit" when Detective Carter started looking for him in season 1. Even some of gangsters, corrupt people like HR and government agencies like the FBI know him as a person who keeps on showing up at locations of crimes and wearing a suit.

Very few like Elias, Finch and others on his team know him by sight which are mostly on his side. Only CIA people are against him who know him by face. Even the FBI was not able to recognize him when they arrested him in one episode as other guys were also in suits.

So why doesn't he get rid of the suit, he can wear any other costume? Especially when he could get rid of all the people except the CIA, like in season 2 when the FBI was looking for him.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Because it's a great disguise!

For general, everyday, wear in a big city like New York, a simple dark/black suit is essentially **anonymous**. There are tens of thousands of men wearing them everyday throughout the city.

> Still, he got famous with name "Man in Suit" when Detective Carter started looking for him in Season 1

**Exactly**...all they could describe him as was as "A guy in a suit"...nothing more.

Add in the fact that a suit allows you to go pretty much anywhere that you might need to only adds to usefulness.

Also, Reese can wear body armor under the shirt/coat without it being obvious.

Finally, as the series continued, Reese was operating as a NYPD detective and, AFAIK, they are expected to wear "business dress" unless otherwise required....and a suit would fit right in.

Of course, Reese does wear other "costumes" throughout the show, as and when the situation requires it.

Comment: I. e. see the story of [Polyphemus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphemus)

Comment: Although, Reese wear different clothing on pilot episode. After a while, watching the series again, that makes somewhat awkward look into him